# Modify return type of coroutines use cases

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines, use-case

I initially had api calls written using rxjava now I am converting them to use kotlin coroutines using suspend functions.

I am following use case patters where my use case takes care of threading.

I want my base use case `UseCaseSuspend` to be very generic to return the type of the actual api call.

How can I modify my `UseCaseSuspend` to return any type, I think currently I have it set to return `Unit` which is what I want to change.

OrderRepository - my api call which returns `GenericResponse`

```
  suspend fun notifyOnStSuspend(serviceType: String, id: String, action: TimestampedAction): GenericResponse =
        serviceSuspend.serviceOrderOnSt(serviceType, id, action)
```

OnStUseCaseSuspend which extends UseCaseSuspend

Here is the error on `run` -
`Return type is 'GenericResponse', which is not a subtype of overridden public abstract suspend fun run(params: OnStUseCaseSuspend.Params): Unit defined in com.i6systems.in2plane.clean.domain.UseCaseSuspend`

```
class OnStUseCaseSuspend @Inject constructor(
    private val orderRepository: OrderRepository
) : UseCaseSuspend<GenericResponse, OnStUseCaseSuspend.Params> (){
    override suspend fun run(params: Params) =
        orderRepository.notifyOnStSuspend(params.serviceType, params.id, params.action)

    data class Params(val serviceType: String, val id: String, val action: TimestampedAction)
}
```

UseCaseSuspend -  which is what should be changed I think to return any response as per API call and not specific to GenericResponse

```
abstract class
UseCaseSuspend <out Type, in Params> where Type : Any {

    abstract suspend fun run(params: Params)

    operator fun invoke(params: Params, onResult: (m: Unit) -> Unit = {}) {
        val job = GlobalScope.async(Dispatchers.IO) { run(params) }
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) { onResult(job.await()) }
    }

    class None
}
```

I want to keep `UseCaseSuspend` very generic so that the response can be anything.

How can I do the bellow link but I am not using Either

I was referring to https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture-Kotlin/blob/master/app/src/main/kotlin/com/fernandocejas/sample/core/interactor/UseCase.kt

Thanks
R

Edit:

I added return type for `run` function in `UseCaseSuspend` and it gave me an error on job.await()

[image]

This is the presenter which uses the Onstusecase and the type of response is `Unit` but it should be `Generic Response`

[image]

Comment: Replace Any with Okhttp3 Headers?

Comment: Issue is that your class `OnStUseCaseSuspend.Params` is not extending `Params` available on `UseCaseSuspend`.

Comment: @JeelVankhede thank you for responding, can you elaborate on that please.

Comment: What is the `Params` in your `UseCaseSuspend`?

Comment: Try to define `run` inside `UseCaseSuspend` like this: `abstract suspend fun run(params: Params): Type` (notice the return type)

Comment: @marstran I added return type to `run` on `UseCaseSuspend` and it gave me an error on `job.await()` as type mismatch `Unit` and `Type`. I have updated the question with a screenshot for you

Comment: @JeelVankhede Params is what I pass to the use case as parameters required for api call, Params are defined in `OnStandUseCaseSuspend`. Dont think it is an issue with Params, but it is due to return types which I am not handling correctly

Comment: @BRDroid I guess you also need to change the type of the `onResult` parameter to `onResult: (Type) -> Unit = {}`...

Comment: @marstran that took of the error but in the presenter layer, where I am using the `OnStandUseCaseSuspend`, where I should be expecting `RenericResponse` as the return type when I cann `OnStandUseCaseSuspend` but the return type is `Unit`. I am adding the image on the question which shows the return type

Comment: @BRDroid Seems to me like your code converts the suspending call to a callback. You can get the response through that callback. I think you have to call `onStandUseCaseSuspend(params) { response -> Timber.d("..." + response) }` in the presenter.

Comment: @marstran that makes so much sense, you were absolutely right